# Join two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have two sql queries

Query 1:

```
Select Year, country, state, city, sales from db.sales1 (for current Year)
```

Query 2:

```
Select Year, country, state, city, sales from db.sales2(For last 4 years)
```

Requirement:
Select Current Yr, Country, City, Sales_current, Sales_yr2015, Sales_yr2016 from above 2 queries.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: No offence, but did you try google or bing before posting this question?

Comment: I did, but couldn't find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `UNION ALL`

```
Select Year, country, state, city, sales from db.sales1 
UNION ALL
Select Year, country, state, city, sales from db.sales2
```

Or if you want a more condense report

```
SELECT country, state, city,
       SUM( CASE WHEN Year = 2015 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) as Sales_yr2015,
       SUM( CASE WHEN Year = 2016 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) as Sales_yr2016
FROM (
        Select Year, country, state, city, sales from db.sales1 
        UNION ALL
        Select Year, country, state, city, sales from db.sales2
    ) T
GROUP BY country, state, city
```

Comment: you are very kind to give everything when the OP obviously didn't try anything :)